# Print leaves node parent binary tree

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-tree, return-value

My C++ exercise is about printing leave parent nodes in a binary tree. I've worked on two ideas to accomplish that. They are the following

### Idea 1

```
/* Write a program that finds and prints all vertices of a binary tree which have 
 * successor leaves only */

#include <iostream>

class Node{
  public:
    int data;
    Node* left = nullptr;
    Node* right = nullptr;

    Node(int value){data=value;}
};

bool traverse(Node* node);

bool traverse(Node* node){
  if(!node->left&&!node->right)
    return true;

  if (traverse(node->left)||traverse(node->right)) 
      std::cout<<node->data<<'\t';  

  if(node->left)
    traverse(node->left);

  if (node->right) 
    traverse(node->right);  
}//Non-void function does not return a value in all control paths
```

**Pros:**

What I like about it is that I don't need to add any variables extra variables to it. That is a huge advantage if I want to use that method or a similar implementation in another tree because `Node` class is clean.

**Cons**

My main issue with my `traverse` function is that I don't now how to implement the missing `return false;` statement the compiler complains about. If I do that, there's not gonna be recursion in my understanding.

### Idea 2

```
/* Write a program that finds and prints all vertices of a binary tree which have 
 * successor leaves only */

#include <iostream>

class Node{
  public:
    int data;
    Node* left = nullptr;
    Node* right = nullptr;
    bool isLeaf = false;

    Node(int value){data=value;}
};

void traverse(Node* node);

void traverse(Node* node){
  if(!node->left&&!node->right){
    node->isLeaf = true;
    return;
  }

  if (node->left||node->right) 
      std::cout<<node->data<<'\t';  

  if(node->left)
    traverse(node->left);

  if (node->right) 
    traverse(node->right);  
}
```

**Pros:**

I feel idea 2 is more effective and less adventurous in some way.

**Cons**

What I don't like about it is that it's got an extra variable that perhaps is not very useful if I put it into a more comprehensive tree class. To put it simpler, idea 2 looks less clean than 1

**Bug**

There's something about these two ideas that I can't figure out. Why don't they loop recursively? There's a `return` statement in both that avoids an infinite loop and the recursive calls happen as long as either `right` or `left` children exit. Can anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong with my `traverse` function please?

**Question**

I'd also like to make **idea 1** work because I like the way it checks if a node is a parent of a leaf node by calling itself. How can I deal with the missing `return false;` statement the compiler wants me to include?

**Edit**

Just want to add the `main` function I created for them so you guys can see how I built the tree.

```
int main(){
  Node* root = new Node(1);
  root->left = new Node(2);
  root->right = new Node(3);
  root->left->left = new Node(4);
  root->left->right = new Node (5);
  root->right->left = new Node(6);
  root->right->right = new Node(7);

  traverse(root);
  return 0;
}
```

### Update

My code isn't far from the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76345143/20302906) as RandomBits told me. He/She pointed out some flaws in it and I tested it in a sandbox. The result is good but it prints leaf parents each time the function is called, something I don't understand now.

Comment: what is meant with "successor" nodes? I would expect such a term in an *ordered* tree. For instance, in a binary *search* tree, a successor of a node can never be its left child. It it has a right child, then its successor is somewhere in that subtree. What does "successor" mean here?

Comment: Could you provide some more context behind the `bool` prototype...Is it a requirement? What are you going to use the method for? `pre-order` walk really has no other use that printing the contents. If you are trying to find the predecessor or the sucesor then you should look at `in-order` traversal

Comment: Hi @trincot! Thanks for asking. Basically the exercise is about printing parent node with leaves only and leaves are at the bottom level of the tree.

Comment: Hey @TheCompile-TimeComedian! Just noticed that the prototype was redundant. I'm gonna read again about `in-order` traversal. The aim of the exercise is to print only leaves parent node nodes so `in-order` traversal makes sense.

Comment: @JuanJáuregui well if the task was to print "*print only leaves parent node nodes*" than any traversal would do. You would need the `in-order` traversal if you wanted to find the **successor** or the **predecessor**. The 3rd code block in my answer should be what you are looking for. If it's not please provide more detail so we can help you :-)

Comment: I'm actually reading your answer right now and testing it in a sandbox just before checking it as the right answer. It definitely works but I'm making sure I understand it thoroughly. My returning bool function doesn't work well I'm afraid so I'm going for your code this time. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took some time but I did it. Quite happy with the result, learned a lot from doing this exercise

```
/* Write a program that finds and prints all vertices of a binary tree which have 
 * successor leaves only */

#include <iostream>

class Node{
  public:
    int data;
    Node* left = nullptr;
    Node* right = nullptr;

    Node(int value){data=value;}
};

bool isLeaf(Node* node){
  return !node->left&&!node->right;
}

bool isParent(Node* node){
  if(node)
    return (isLeaf(node->left)||isLeaf(node->right));
  else
    return false;
}

void printParent(Node* node){
  if(node == nullptr)
    return;

  if(!isLeaf(node)&&isParent(node))
    std::cout<<node->data<<'\n';

  if (node->left) 
    printParent(node->left);
  
  if (node->right) 
    printParent(node->right);  
}

int main(){
  Node* root = new Node(1);
  root->left = new Node(2);
  root->right = new Node(3);
  root->left->left = new Node(4);
  root->left->left->right = new Node(10);
  root->left->left->left = new Node(11);
  root->left->right = new Node (5);
  root->right->left = new Node(6);
  root->right->right = new Node(7);

  printParent(root);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Idea 1` code you posted is very close, but the compiler warning might not be the only issue.

I think you are right in leaning towards a solution that doesn't require extra data in the `Node` structure. `Idea 1` would be considered a `non-intrusive` solution and `Idea 2` an `intrusive` solution.

- The first conditional returns `true` for the case where there are no children, i.e. a leaf node. All other cases are `false`, so simply return `false` at the end of the function.
- I think you only want to print the node if a `traverse` of both the `left` and `right` child returns true, i.e. both children are leaf nodes, but I might not understand the problem exactly.

```cpp
// Returns true if this node is a leaf, otherwise, false.
bool traverse(Node* node){

  if(!node->left&&!node->right)
    return true;

  // I think you want an `and` here, i.e. both children must be leaves
  if (traverse(node->left)&&traverse(node->right)) 
      std::cout<<node->data<<'\t';  

  if(node->left)
    traverse(node->left);

  if (node->right) 
    traverse(node->right);

  // There are at least some children, so not a leaf.
  return false;  
}
```

Comment: Hi @RandomBits! Thanks for contributing to answering the question. `return false;` at the end of the function did help. Still not getting the recursion work properly, that's still confusing.

Comment: This is the closest answer right now. Adding `&&` instead of `||` in the second conditional plus `return false` at the end gives me almost the right result. For some reason the first leaf parent is being printed twice. I'm finding out why

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, you are traversing the tree in `pre-order` (printing and then "*walking*" the tree left and right).

I don't fully understand why you would use `bool` in this case since those functions/methods are usually void. You are on the right track, recursion is your best friend in `Data Structures`.

Here is my implementation for `pre-order` `type void`:

```
void traverse(Node* node /*root*/) {
  if(node == nullptr) {
    return; //do nothing
    
  }else if(node != nullptr){ //could just be an else
    std::cout << node -> data << "\t";
    
    traverse(root -> left); //walk left
    
    traverse(root -> right); //walk right
  }
}
```

Here is my implementation of `printLeafNodes` `type void`:

```
void printLeafNodes(Node* node) {
  if (node == nullptr) {
    return; 
  }

  if (node->left == nullptr && node->right == nullptr) {
    std::cout << node->data << "\t";
  }
  printLeafNodes(node->left); 
  printLeafNodes(node->right); 
}
```

**Edit:**

I seemed to misunderstand your question in the first place, I am guessing you want to print all vertices of a binary tree that have
successor leaves only.

**Code**:

```
void traverse(Node* node) {
    if (!node)
        return;

    if (node->left && !node->left->left && !node->left->right)
        std::cout << node->left->data << '\t';

    if (node->right && !node->right->left && !node->right->right)
        std::cout << node->right->data << '\t';

    traverse(node->left);
    traverse(node->right);
}
```

This should answer your question, I hope.

Essentially the same thing, but here you check if it's actually a leaf node. No `left` or `right` child means `leaf` node

I hope you are familiar with recursion because this is  *imo* a very simple example and quite self-explanatory.  This won't go into an infinite loop since as soon as a child node == `nullptr` it returns.

To answer your question: *Why don't they loop recursively?* It's hard to say without more context or without seeing your main. You are returning early if `node->left` or `node->right` is `nullptr` perhaps your tree is `skewed` or `degenerate`.

Comment: Hi @The Compile-Time Comedian! Just tested your code after reading your answers. The output is 4 5 6 7 instead of just 4 5 as expected I'm afraid. I'll come back to it tomorrow to see what's going on with it. I used https://cpp.sh/ to test it by the way. Oh sorry, that was misleading I'm gonna include the `main` function in the question as an edit.

Comment: No worries. SO is not a "code review" service but if you paste your code [here](https://godbolt.org) and reply with a comment (with the same link) we can figure out what the issue was. Sounds good?

Comment: Yeah, that'd be great! Here you go the [link](https://godbolt.org/), anyway I'll come back to this tomorrow.

Comment: @JuanJáuregui yeah you have to paste your code in there and copy the link...All I can see is my comment saying "Paste your code here"

Comment: > `recursion is your best friend in Data Structures.` Not necessarily. Iterative solution use less system resources and in some cases may be faster. Among other things, recursion can cause `stack overflow`.

Comment: @pacmaninbw Ok, fair point... Recursion needs more resources (generating new stack frames) and is a pain in the a** to debug, but it also makes the code "more" readable. Recursion is your best friend in (low-level) Data Structures applications like this question for example. Consider (BFS) or level-order traversal, the iterative solution is 3 times as long as your recursive solution.

Comment: I have a fair amount of experience with recursion, see [my question on code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/132876/knights-tour-improved-refactored-recursive-breadth-first-search-for).

Comment: I noticed a slight performance difference [here](https://godbolt.org)

Comment: @TheCompile-TimeComedian I just double-checked the link I posted in my previous comment yesterday and the code was. Also, I clicked on your link and saw that the code was there as well.

Comment: Hi @pacmaninbw! Thanks for contributing. Indeed, there are cases where iterative implementation works better than recursion. I remember that factorials are a good example even though there are not a data structure, wish I had an example with data structures now. BTW I tried to read your code review question but I didn't understand it, so I'll keep going working on my skills to be able to read code like that

Comment: @JuanJáuregui good example where recursion sucks is the Fibonacci sequence, if you are using a 64bit integer to compute huge numbers it's going to gobble up your resources (2^n time complexity and n space complexity). Oh, and I don't really know how compiler explorer works since when I click my link I see my graph implementation...

Comment: @TheCompile-TimeComedian that's alright! I tested this answer [here](https://t.ly/8Jg9) (needed a link shortener by the way) with an unbalanced binary tree. The output is a bit strange, I'll take a look at it again tomorrow though :)

Comment: @wavesinaroom Why would you want to print 4 and 5? Thats the left "subtree" of your main tree? Isn't your task to "*Write a program that finds and prints all vertices of a binary tree which have successor leaves only*"?

Comment: @TheCompile-TimeComedian sorry, my bad! Actually the output should be 2 and 3 only

Comment: @wavesinaroom [here](https://godbolt.org), I think this is what you're looking for...I tested it on a bigger tree and it prints `4 5 6 7` which is exactly what you want.

Comment: @TheCompile-TimeComedian sorry man I opened the link and there was nothing but `int square(int num){return num * num)` That happened to my as well yesterday when I tried to share some code with you

Comment: Does [this](https://cpp.sh) work?

Answer (score -1):

I don't see an actual question, but I ran into problem with displaying trees once they got deep and wide. I ended up printing it "sideways" using head-first recursion, which works well for me:

```
void BinTree::showTree(const Node *ptr, const int depth) {
        if(ptr->right != nullptr) {
                showTree(ptr->right, depth + 1);
        }
        cout << string(depth, '\t') << ptr->val << endl;
        if(ptr->left != nullptr) {
                showTree(ptr->left, depth + 1);
        }
}
```

Just my $0.02

Comment: Hi @David Rosario! Thanks for your answer. My question was about finding a way to deal with `idea 1` missing return statement and why my function didn't loop recursively. On the other hand I like your answer and I went for that approach to solve another problem (Level order binary tree traversal). I'll use it as a back up plan if I can't make `idea 1` work.